# Why is my Web Forms for Marketers not writing to my SQL database

Tags: sql-server, sitecore

I have loaded WFFM and I overrided the "SaveToDatabase" function with the following:

https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/W/WEB_FORMS_FOR_MARKETERS_8X_SQL_PROVIDER.aspx

my forms work fine, but when I check SQL, there is nothing there. 
Where can I check if there are any errors? I already looked in logs, but I am not seeing anything. and I changed my user profile to have full authority.

Comment: We'd like to try and and help you, but our magic crystal balls are coincidentally ALL in the shop for annual service, so we can't read your mind to see what your code is doing. So... sorry, can't help.

Comment: okay, that's funny

Comment: There is no, code Sitecore's Web Forms for Marketers is a tool for customers, who have little coding experience to drop a form on a placeholder, and create input fields and such. there is a submit function to email, and one to SaveToDatabase ... the current 8.0 uses MongoDB, I overrided that to use SQL. I was trying to see if anyone else had used this and had a similar Experience

Comment: What Sitecore version and what Wffm are you using ? Are you using without XDB ?

Comment: I haven't used that module/package. Anyway, have you checked that you have the "overrided" Save to database action on the submit actions for your form?

Comment: thank you for all of your comments and assistance. at this point we are exploring many alternatives, such as reinstalling this package on a device, that does not currently have WFFM. I did successfully load WFFM and built a form and placed it on the page, styled it. my only issue is trying to get the data from the form into SQL. that is the current issue.

Comment: I have checked the Override settings in SavetoDatabase ... its all good.

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint in your code to understand if the action is being triggered? Maybe is easier to just create a custom save to db? https://doc.sitecore.net/web_forms_for_marketers/working_with_actions_and_validations/save_actions/create_a_new_save_action

Comment: this is resolved guys ... thanks for all of your help